# Change design collection view cell when I redimensioned

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I have a problem , I have a collection view dynamic , when start I have 3 rows but when change slider , change the number of rows in collection and adapted the design , the problem is the design is wrong I can try with `self.myCarouselView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()`
 but don't worked , any help?
In size cell I have this code:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: myCollection.bounds.size.width/CGFloat(numberOfYears), height: 120)
    }
```

my first image:
[image]

and the image finally when I change te rows:
[image]

The curiosity is when i click in circle , the design change to format correct ...

Answer (score 0):

```
Create one class from UICollectionViewFlowLayout, override the flow layout using this code

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.minimumLineSpacing = 1.0;
        self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1.0;
        self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
    }
    return self;
}

- (CGSize)itemSize
{
    NSInteger numberOfColumns = 3;

    CGFloat itemWidth = (CGRectGetWidth(self.collectionView.frame) - (numberOfColumns - 1)) / numberOfColumns;
    return CGSizeMake(itemWidth, itemWidth);
}
```

Comment: Sorry , does not solve anything , the problem not is class layout.